# Add Custom User Field (Dropdown) in Moodle

Tags: moodle

Hi I need to add Custom User Field (Dropdown) in Moodle. I know I can add it through https://docs.moodle.org/24/en/User_profile_fields and https://docs.moodle.org/dev/User_profile_fields

I went ahead with above method and added dropdown accordingly. However, when I see it in database, {user_info_field} it shows only one row with my select fields seperated by new line. Screenshot is listed.

[image: {user_info_field} screenshot]

I want these params to be appear in separate rows. Because, I've few development in pipeline which involves creation of custom invoicing plugin that allows to store pricing for each university.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using a custom field in this way for invoicing. I would create a local plugin that creates a table with the userid / universityid pair and another table with the univserityid and name, used as a lookup. Then build some admin interfaces around that and only give admins/managers access. So they are in control of what university the user belongs to for invoicing purposes.

Comment: That's awesome information. Can you post this as an answer?

Comment: One Small Question.. Is it possible to render this local plugin "university field" on existing Student Registration Form?

Comment: You can but you would need to modify the core code to include the drop down and some code to update the local table. It's easy enough to do though. The problem is that depends on the student to select the correct university. If they make a mistake, then the wrong university will be invoiced. I think that should be the responsibility for an admin/manager/finance department rather than the student. Or maybe synchronise the data with an external system.

Comment: You are correct. We may also avoid to update core code as it may cause a problem when updating to newer version of Moodle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Used in built cohort system to categorized users in different University.  Here I didn't have to create custom profile field.

For invoicing plugin, I will manipulate same cohorts (in my case University) by creating local plugin which adds tables to database field. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

That is how dropdown fields store their options in Moodle - all the values, separated by newlines.

If you want a list of possible values, retrieve  mdl_user_info_field.param1 then use explode("\n", $fieldvalue).

Comment: I know,  i can do that.  but is there any way to seperate these dropdown rows?  I will be using it for seperate plugin.

Comment: You've not made it clear what is stopping another plugin from accessing these values and just calling 'explode' to separate them. Are you wanting to implement a feature that requires creating a lookup table based on these features? If so, you can do that in PHP.

Comment: That will be used for seperate Invoicing Plugin where each University will have separate pricing and that can be displayed as an invoice to Admin and Manager.