# Dynamic dropdown custom field in moodle

Tags: moodle

I want to create a dynamic(database driven) custom profile field in moodle.
it shd take the data of the university table which is customly made by us.it shd be a dropdown that should populate the university name from the database. This custom field should be visible in adding a new user page.

Plz help me with this topic

Comment: if this field is attached to a user, have a look here: https://docs.moodle.org/29/en/User_profile_fields

Comment: Need to add the same custom user field. But the dropdown menu in it. Shd be data driven from the university table

Comment: Please provide more information in your question then, especially when it comes to the "university" table. Without explaining what this table is and how it acts, etc. this question isn't going to go far. Why do you even need a custom table?

Comment: Tanmay - http://stackoverflow.com/a/31024527/4261569 see this answer

Comment: It will surely solve my problem. Thanks sahil